# Is there a way to show a custom popup on clicking a custom button which is in a cell in DataGrid in DevExpress?

Tags: javascript, angular, devexpress

I will have a separate column comprising of Approve and Reject Buttons. On clicking the approve button, it is expected that a custom popup is thrown stating ' Are you sure you want to approve'. The popup will have two buttons, yes(click event directed to a function) and no brings the user back to the same page.

Same is expected for the Reject button.

Code implemented in typescript (Angular 9 & above).

Please advise. TIA!

Comment: Are you using material based dialog box or ngxbootstrap based dialog box?

Comment: It is a dx-data-grid in which i have a column that comprises approve/reject for each row. a pop-up is expected basis the button click

Answer (score 0):

What you should do depends on which UI component library you are using. Virtually all UI component libraries have a modal component. So use the modal component that your library offers. e.g. Angular Material modal, ngx bootstrap modal, etc

However, if you just want to make your own custom modal its pretty easy. For example.

html:

```
<div>
  ...
  the main content for this component
  <button (click)="openModal()">open modal</button>
</div>

<div class="custom-modal-component" [class.hidden]="showModal">
  hello I am a modal
  <button (click)="closeModal()">close modal</button>      
  <button (click)="doSomethingAndCloseModal()">do something</button>      
</div>
```

scss:

```
.custom-modal-component {

  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  margin-top: -250px;
  z-index: 100;

  &.hidden {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

ts:

```
showModal = false

openModal() {
  this.showModal = true
}

closeModal() {
  this.showModal = false
}

doSomethingAndCloseModal() {
  // do something code here
  this.closeModal()
}
```

You might want to enhance this custom solution by adding a background overlay, making it reusable, etc - reusability here ensures separation of concerns. With focus on reusability, the use of content projection is a must!

Comment: I am using Angular DevExpress in which there is a DataGrid component for which I need to implement a popup on button click. The button is present in a column of the grid. Hence, I guess this won't suffice. FYI - https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/

Comment: If devextreme allow you to call a custom function when a button is clicked (which would be very weird if they didnt) then this should work fine since it would be overlaid on top of the grid - alternatively, use the devextreme dialog https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Common/Utils/ui/dialog/

Comment: Go through this link https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/PopupEditing/Angular/Light/

Comment: nice loading spinner

Comment: @SarathMohandas These popups for edit/delete buttons(provided in the link) are fixed for editing and deleting and we can't change the underlying delete event attached to it. Seems, not feasible

Comment: @DivyaKampasi, you can use  <dxi-column
            dataField="Operations"
            [visible]="false"> <edit-modal></edit-modal> // by danday74
        </dxi-column>

Comment: @DivyaKampasi, you can add the above answer to the <edit-modal> by this, I guess you will custom edit.